Best Practices for Using testTag in Jetpack Compose
I’m currently exploring best practices for UI testing in Compose and noticed the use of testTag for component identification. While I understand its utility for stable UI tests, I'm concerned about whether introducing testTag might contradict the principles of reactive programming
Could you guys share your insights on the following points?

Does using testTag conflict with the reactive programming approach that Compose advocates?

Is it a common practice to include testTag in the production code, or should it be limited to debug builds?

Are there alternative strategies for UI testing in Compose that might mitigate the need for testTag?


Thank you!
Are there alternative strategies for UI testing in Compose that might mitigate the need for testTag?

Had the same question and found out about:
https://proandroiddev.com/stop-using-test-tags-in-the-jetpack-compose-production-code-b98e2679221f
Short summary:
Use contentDescriptor if possible; testTags pollute your production code.
*However testTag may be useful if you do parametrized tests. It may also be possible to add a testTag by your test itsself from "outside" so that you might be able to organize your test a bit better.
But in most times it should be feasible to find your components using contentDescriptor.

Thanks for your answer.
I understand the preference for using contentDescription over testTag to avoid code pollution. However, my app supports multiple languages (10+), which means contentDescription changes with language settings. This variability could complicate automated testing. What do you suggest in this case?

by support means, that you are displaying text in different languages in the same element?
Then you should have your texts tranlations inside an string-.xml right?
It should then be possible to use the resourceIdentifier to map the correct text inside your test.
Usually the contentDescription is used for the description of, lets say, an icon. This enables a screen-reader to transform the ui as speech to the user.
However in textViews this is always automatically the contained text which might complexiate your case a bit, but using the resourceIdentifier it should be solveable

The key then is to mock the method, that retreives the string, in your test.
If you use getString(), than mock that. If you have an UI state handing over than its even easier and may decide your test what to insert.
mock getString:
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/local-tests#mockable-library
If not helpful yet it would be nice, if you could also add an code-example to your question.
This also might be helpful (if not known yet)
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/accessibility
